# how to play audio through speakers during a voice call

Tags: android, audio-streaming

when a voice call is established, I want to play audio in an stream so that the one at the other end of the call can hear the audio, but as it is mentioned in documents it is not possible.
so I decided to play that audio through the speakers with maximum volume so that the microphone can *hear* it (in general this a really ugly workaround but as it is going to be done in a special situation in my app, no problem!!!).
now the problem is this that when the call is established the system reduces the volume of my audio. how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you call [`setSpeakerphoneOn`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean))?

Comment: @Michael NO :( should I call that when a call is established?

Comment: Yes, if you want the audio routed to the loudspeaker. Note that the voice call audio also will be routed to the loudspeaker (there's no way around that).

Comment: @Soheil, did you managed to get the other side to hear played sound? On my case, seems that echo cancellations kills the transfer.

Comment: hey you able to play a recorded sound in speaker or mic during a call..?i have to done the same .if u done then please help me .